# TSql performance issue

Tags: sql-server

Below is the  query. I want to improve performance. Please guide me

```
Declare @guidTenantId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
Declare @guidPriceBookId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
Declare @strTextSearch nvarchar(100) = NULL
Declare @bitHasProdServTemplate bit = 0

DECLARE @guidPriceBookLineRelation UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
DECLARE @guidProductRelation UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
declare @guidProdServiceTemplateContext UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 



BEGIN

SELECT 
        TB.PBL_IT_GUID,
        TB.PBL_TN_GUID,
        TB.PBL_LineContext,
        TB.PBL_UnitofMeasure,
        TB.PBL_PriceType,
        TB.PBL_Price,
        TB.PBL_StartDate,
        TB.PBL_EndDate,
        PR_IT_GUID,
        IT_Name,
        PR_ProductNumber,
        PR_MVA
FROM     
(    
        SELECT IR_IT_GUID_TO,IR_CLSID,TA.PBL_IT_GUID,
            TA.PBL_TN_GUID,
            TA.PBL_LineContext,
            TA.PBL_UnitofMeasure,
            TA.PBL_PriceType,
            TA.PBL_Price,
            TA.PBL_StartDate,
            TA.PBL_EndDate      
        FROM        
        (
            SELECT 
                PBL_IT_GUID,
                PBL_TN_GUID,
                PBL_LineContext,
                PBL_UnitofMeasure,
                PBL_PriceType,
                PBL_Price,
                PBL_StartDate,
                PBL_EndDate

            FROM
                dbo.PBL_PriceBookLines INNER JOIN IR_ItemRelation ON PBL_IT_GUID = IR_IT_GUID_From      
                WHERE IR_IT_GUID_To = @guidPriceBookId  
                AND IR_CLSID = @guidPriceBookLineRelation
                AND PBL_TN_GUID = @guidTenantId
        ) AS TA INNER JOIN IR_ItemRelation  ON  IR_IT_GUID_From = TA.PBL_IT_GUID 
) AS TB         



       INNER JOIN IT_Item ON IT_Item.IT_GUID = TB.IR_IT_GUID_TO 
        INNER JOIN dbo.PR_Product ON IT_Item.IT_GUID = PR_IT_GUID
        INNER JOIN dbo.IR_ItemRelation [IR] ON [IR].IR_IT_GUID_From = PR_IT_GUID AND [IR].IR_CLSID = @guidProdServiceTemplateContext        
        WHERE TB.IR_CLSID = @guidProductRelation
        AND (@strTextSearch is null OR(@strTextSearch is not null AND( IT_Name LIKE '%'+@strTextSearch+'%')))

END
```

Comment: You need to add column aliases to the query so it is clear where the columns are coming from.

Comment: what did you already try?

Comment: table-structure would be very very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the normal places:

1. Turn on statistics io and check which table causes most I/O.
2. Turn on actual execution plan and look for expensive operations (scans, spools, thick lines, key lookups for huge number of rows) and maybe big differences between estimated and actual row counts. -- and remember that the percentages are just estimates.
3. Check indexing for columns used in joins and with (simple / SARGable) search criteria

Without details it's really not possible to give exact recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, as we don't know your table-structure and where the columns exactly come from BUT what i don't see is why your query is nested more than once!? Maybe it could look like this:

```
SELECT  PBL.PBL_IT_GUID,
        PBL.PBL_TN_GUID,
        PBL.PBL_LineContext,
        PBL.PBL_UnitofMeasure,
        PBL.PBL_PriceType,
        PBL.PBL_Price,
        PBL.PBL_StartDate,
        PBL.PBL_EndDate,
        PR.PR_IT_GUID,
        IT.IT_Name,
        PR.PR_ProductNumber,
        PR.PR_MVA
FROM    dbo.PBL_PriceBookLines PBL 
        INNER JOIN dbo.IR_ItemRelation IR1 ON PBL.PBL_IT_GUID = IR1.IR_IT_GUID_From
        INNER JOIN dbo.IT_Item IT ON IT.IT_GUID = IR1.IR_IT_GUID_TO 
        INNER JOIN dbo.PR_Product PR ON IT.IT_GUID = PR.PR_IT_GUID
        INNER JOIN dbo.IR_ItemRelation IR2 ON IR2.IR_IT_GUID_From = PR.PR_IT_GUID        
WHERE   IR1.IR_IT_GUID_To = @guidPriceBookId  
        AND IR1.IR_CLSID = @guidPriceBookLineRelation
        AND PBL.PBL_TN_GUID = @guidTenantId
        AND IR2.IR_CLSID = @guidProdServiceTemplateContext    
        AND IR1.IR_CLSID = @guidProductRelation
        AND (
                @strTextSearch IS NULL 
            OR
            (
                @strTextSearch IS NOT NULL 
                AND IT.IT_Name LIKE '%'+@strTextSearch+'%'
            )
            )
```

This query may not be much faster but at least easier to read and you can get better answers and a meaningful execution plan.

Comment: In my database every thing is classified as unit,item and attribute .There are unit to unit relation ,unit to item relation and so on. IR_ItemRelation table gives relation between item to item .There are relation context.

Comment: In my database every thing is classified as unit,item and attribute .There are unit to unit relation ,unit to item relation and so on. IR_ItemRelation table gives relation between item to item .There are relation context. For example structure of IR_ITemRelation is (IR_Clsid,IR_From,IR_To) where   IR_Clsid is unique context through which two items are linked. IT_item table contains all items basic info like name etc. Which means it is base table for items.

Comment: ok but what everbody here needs here are some informations! How many rows for the tables? Primary Keys? Indexes? Datatypes? ....

Comment: Very sorry ,Could not look  update from you.PBL_IT_GUID is primary key in PBL_PriceBookLines  and IT_Guid is primary key in IT_ITem table there are no indexes . I just want to know is my way of getting data is not optimized.

Comment: Very sorry ,Could not look  update from you.PBL_IT_GUID is primary key in PBL_PriceBookLines  and IT_Guid is primary key in IT_ITem table there are no indexes . I just want to know is my way of getting data is  optimized. I don't have index creation option

Comment: I think the most expensive part is this one `AND IT.IT_Name LIKE '%'+@strTextSearch+'%'`  ... if there is no index on IT.IT_Name